# Can't read object in vector in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem i don't understand why I can't get my value from a vector :

And  I think the error is i about how i use my vector.

i have 3 files :

the Header of my class Group

Group.hpp

```
#ifndef Group_hpp
#define Group_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Etapes.hpp"
using namespace std;


class Group{

    float coefficiant;
    int note;


public:
    Group(float coefficiant,int note);
    float getCoefficiant();
    int getNote();


};


#endif /* Group_hpp */
```

Group.cpp (where I defined the content of my class)

```
#include "Group.hpp"

Group::Group(float coefficiant,int note){
    this->coefficiant = coefficiant;
    this->note = note;
}

float Group::getCoefficiant(){
    return this->coefficiant;
}

int Group::getNote(){
    return this->note;
}
```

and the main :  Where I execute my class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Etapes.hpp"
#include "Group.hpp"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    vector<Group> listGroup;
    listGroup.push_back(*new Group(2.2,5));

    for(int i = 0;i<listGroup.size();i++){
        cout<<listGroup[i].getCoefficiant()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am really lock on this class.

Thank you

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: You need to describe the error you are getting and/or how it's not working.

Comment: Why people who are in **college** already don't understand that when they ask 'why do I have a problem' they need to describe the problem as well? Is school education system totally failing?

Comment: @SergeyA, the art/skill of communication fails many a people. It must be a hard skill to teach.

Comment: @SergeyA it's not only communication skills lacking, it's just that learning programming is about repetition. It's just like any language (french, english, etc), you read a sentence, you might understand it. But phrasing a proper sentence doesn't always come as easily.

Comment: It works fine when everything is one file. http://ideone.com/A9cwvp. I don't see why it wouldn't work with multiple files. Of course, you haven't described what makes you think that your code isn't working.

Comment: yep I also ran in one unique file, as is, and there is no problem at all.

Comment: Your program contains at least four files, and you haven't shown, "Etapes.hpp".

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;` from your `Group.hpp` header file since nothing in the header file uses symbols in the `std` namespace.  Similarly, you can eliminate the `#includes` too.  Maybe move this stuff to the source file.

Comment: A better coding practice is to list the identifiers you are using from `std`, such as `using std::cout;` rather than the all inclusive `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Save yourself some typing, stop with the `this->` syntax.  Access the member variables and methods directly.  The more you type, the high possibility of injecting defects into your code (especially typos).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Even worse, the unused `using` can become _very_ used, for it leaks into any other translation unit that `#include`s the header, thus potentially conflicting with names elsewhere and causing extreme headaches. Hence why using `using` in headers at global scope is routinely discouraged. (I say "global scope" because I'm sure `using` can be useful in template functions.) [all wordplay intended]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
listGroup.push_back(*new Group(2.2,5));
```

just use

```
listGroup.push_back(Group(2.2,5));
```

One of the big advantages of STL containers it that they encapsulate dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: It's a bit more severe than "don't need to". its an instant memory leak

Comment: `listGroup.push_back(Group(2.2,5));` should work as well.

Comment: While this is, indeed, correct, it doesn't answer the question at hand, and as such, doesn't deserve to be an answer on it's own (it could be added to an answer or put as comment).

Comment: Even better, use `listGroup.emplace_back(2.2, 5);`

However, this answer doesn't explain why the OP's initial code is wrong, since although the memory leak, both lines are effectively equivalent.

Comment: @SergeyA: What is the answer then?

Comment: @FrankPuffer, I do not know, because OP didn't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: He wrote "i don't understand why I can't get my value from a vector" and I think my answer explains the main reason.